# Leaflet js, pass geoJSON to setView

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet.js map that has a square that come from an external GeoJSON file.
I want to pass the center of the square (I calculated  the coordinates ) to the setView function, how do I convert the coordinates? (When I passed the values from the the GeoJSON directly to setView It showed some other place, as I understand it doesn't use the same coordinate reference system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you just passed coordinates with the wrong order:

- In GeoJSON, coordinates are `[longitude, latitude]`
- In Leaflet, they are expected as `[latitude, longitude]`